# Dirty read or phantom read in multiple insert transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I understand the examples given for "dirty reads" and "phantom reads" on the wikipedia page for [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Dirty_reads_.28Uncommitted_Dependency.29). However I'm not sure how to categorise the following situation and what isolation level or different strategy to apply in order to avoid this situation.

1. Transaction 1: Inserts row in table A
2. Transaction 2: Selects row in table A
3. Transaction 2: Selects row in table B based on something in the previous read
4. <del>Transaction 2: Commit</del>
5. Transaction 1: Inserts row in table B
6. Transaction 1: Commit

The problem is that Transaction 2 selects something in B before T1 finished writing in both tables. The select in step 3 might need to select the row inserted in 5 to be correct. Is this a dirty read, phantom read or neither. Would a READ_COMMITTED isolation level be enough to avoid problems? As I understand it, with READ_COMMITTED T2 should not read the new row inserted by T1 at that point.

Comment: What are you committing in step 4 - I don't see Transaction 2 modifying any data?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Since it's just SELECTS there's no actual commit on T2. I just added it to show that there are no more operations on that transaction. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *dirty read*. In `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level the query in step 2 will not return the row you have inserted in step 1 but haven't committed yet, thus preventing the unsuccessful attempt to access data that hasn't been inserted yet.

A *phantom read* would mean that you are executing the *same* query twice inside Transaction 2 and getting a different set of results.

Comment: Just to make sure: just T2 should have isolation level READ_COMMITTED? Is the isolation level of T1 relevant? In some places the doc says _"This level prohibits a transaction from reading a row with uncommitted changes in it"_ which suggests that the reading transaction should have READ_COMMITTED while in other places the docs say _"In this isolation level, DBMS implementation keeps write locks"_ which suggests that the writing transaction should be the one with READ_COMMITTED.

Comment: @CristianVrabie: The READ_COMMITTED should be specified for T2, as it affects the locking behavior when reading. See this link for an example: http://www.herongyang.com/MySQL/Transaction-Isolation-Level-Read-Uncommitted.html

Also note that the default transaction isolation level in InnoDB is REPEATABLE READ, which is even more isolated than READ COMMITTED.